# helm-ag , use word at point as input conditionally

Tags: helm, helm-projectile, helm-ag

I'd like to create two keybindings for `helm-do-ag-project-root` or `helm-project-ag`

where one would have `(setq helm-ag-insert-at-point nil)`
and one would have `(setq helm-ag-insert-at-point 'symbol)`

So that I can selectively use word at-point for search.

Below is my attempt but not working.

```
 (use-package helm-projectile
   :ensure t
   :config

    (defun my-helm-grep-do-git-grep ()
      (setq helm-ag-insert-at-point nil)
      (helm-projectile-ag)
      )
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-c g") 'my-helm-grep-do-git-grep)

    (defun my-helm-grep-do-git-grep-at-point ()
      (setq helm-ag-insert-at-point 'symbol)
      (helm-projectile-ag)
      )
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-c k") 'my-helm-grep-do-git-grep-at-point)


   )
```

Comment: See this for an alternative solution which always inserts the symbol, but lets you overtype it if you don't want it: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53219/2498

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me when I was using `helm-ag`:

```lisp
(defun mu-helm-ag-thing-at-point ()
  "Search the symbol at point with `helm-ag'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((helm-ag-insert-at-point 'symbol))
    (helm-do-ag-project-root)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make your functions interactive (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html)).

You could also try the `helm-grep-do-git-grep` command, which I think is a lot smarter at solving this issue. For example, it *always* searches the symbol at point if it finds one, but as soon as you start typing the Helm buffer updates automatically to display the new candidates.

Answer (score 0):

In Helm, `M-n` can be used to select thing at point. In most cases.